# Yii2: Assigning javascript event to anchor tag in yii2

Tags: yii2

how to assign javascript onclick event to the anchor tag what is the mapping of it in yii2

```
<a style="margin-left: 30px;" href="" onclick="$('#createTeamForm').show(500); $('#createTeamForm').css('display','')"> Create Team</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this like below:

```
\yii\helpers\Html::a('Create Team',\yii\helpers\Url::to('url'),['onclick'=>"$('#createTeamForm').show(500);$('#createTeamForm').css('display','')",'style'=>'margin-left: 30px;']);
```