# Yii2 - Assign on click event to an anchor tag in return value of a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am new to Yii2 and web programming so excuse perhaps my lack of knowledge or even dumb requestions.

I have divided my site into 4 div container. In one container (#untenrechts(edited: lowerright)) i use a grid view and if i click on "customer_name"(edited) i want to refresh another container (#obenlinks(edited: #upperleft)) with the detail view of the chosen customer(edited) without reloading the complete page, just the container.

At the moment it only works with manually reloading to show the selected details of the chosen customer(edited).

I have problems to get the syntax in the return value of the anonymous function. I just dont get it, how to use the onclick event here.

I searched a lot and the best result i got was this one here:
[Yii2: Assigning javascript event to anchor tag in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356300/yii2-assigning-javascript-event-to-anchor-tag-in-yii2)

But that is my problem. This solution isnt part of a return value. So i hope some friendly guys here could help me to get the right way or understanding of that.

Thanks in forward

**Edit:** I have to apologize, because i posted questions as to look for project_detail, but i need the customer_detail. No great difference in code, but for understanding my problem. I also changed the div container names to english ones, for better understanding. I updated my question.

I now tried to implement the given suggestions and posted (hopefully) all relevant code. Now i just get an #404 Error.

Sadly i need more help to understand this line:

```
return Html::a($model->company_name, ['#.'], ['data'=>['customers'=>$model->id],'class' => 'customer_details']);
```

The link always tries to call "/site/#.". I tried other adresses, but get always the same error.

_LIST.PHP

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\Customers;
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

    $this->registerJs("
    $(document).on('click','a.customer_details',function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:'/customers/view', 
    data:{id:id},
    success:function(data){($'#obenlinks').html(data)},
    error:function(xhr,statusCode,errorText){alert(errorText)}
});
});
", yii\web\View::POS_READY);


?>


   <div class="row" style="position:relative; left: 30px;">    
    <div id="upperleft" class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lightgreen; overflow: scroll; width:550px; height:300px; border: 1px solid black">


        <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model2,
        'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'customer_number',
        'company_name',
        'customer_type',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'customer_since',
        'street_name',
        'street_number',
        'zipcode',
        'city',
        ],
        ]) ?>
        <?php Pjax::end();?>
    </div>




    <div id="upperright" class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lightblue; overflow: scroll; width:550px; height:300px;border: 1px solid black">

       EMPTY DIV CONTAINER

    </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row" style="position:relative; left: 30px;">    
    <div id="lowerleft" class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lightgrey; overflow: scroll; width:550px; height:300px;border: 1px solid black">

        EMPTY DIV CONTAINER

    </div>



    <div id="lowerright" class="col-md-6" style="background-color:orange; overflow: scroll; width:550px; height:300px;border: 1px solid black">

        GRIDVIEW ALL CUSTOMERS

        <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

                'columns' => [

                    'customer_number',
                    [
                        'label' => 'Firmenname',
                        'attribute' => 'company_name',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value' => function ($model) { 
                            if ($model->company_name == "Privat"){  
                                return " "; 
                            }
                            else {
                        return Html::a($model->company_name, ['#.'], ['data'=>['customers'=>$model->id],'class' => 'customer_details']);
                            }
                        },
                    ],

                    [
                        'label' => 'Privatkunde',
                        'attribute' => 'firstname',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value' => function ($model) {
                            return Html::a($model->firstname . ' ' . $model->lastname, ['customers/view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                        }
                    ],           
                    [
                        'label' => 'Projekte',
                        'attribute' => 'projects.project_name',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value' => function ($model) {
                            $selectproject='<ul id="selectproject">';

                            foreach ($model->projects as $row) {
                                $selectproject.= "<li value='$row->id'>".Html::a($row->project_name, ['/projects/view', 'id' => $row->id])."</li>";
                            }
                            $selectproject.='</ul>';
                        return $selectproject;

                        },
                    ],



                ],
            ]); ?>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

PRODUCTIONSITE.PHP

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use backend\models\Customers;
use backend\models\Projects;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'Produktivumgebung';
?>


<div>

   <?php echo $this->render('/subviews/_customerssearch', ['model' => $searchModel]); 
         //var_dump ($model->attributes);
   ?>



    <div id="listenboxaussen" style="background-color:blue; position:relative">

        <?=$this->render('//site/frames/_list.php', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'query' => $query,
            'modelProjects' => $modelProjects,
            'searchModelProjects' => $searchModelProjects,
            'dataProviderProjects' => $dataProviderProjects,
            'queryProjects' => $queryProjects,
            'model2' => $model2,



            ))?>;

    </div>
```

SITECONTROLLER.PHP

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use backend\models\Customers;
use backend\models\Projects;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;



/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index','productionsite','start','stop','pause'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionProductionsite($id=0)
    {
        $this->layout = '/production'; 

        if ($id!=0){
            $model2 = Customers::findOne($id);
        }else{
            $model2 = false;
        }

        // Get customer data
        $model = new Customers;
        $searchModel = new \backend\models\CustomersSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $query = Customers::find()->with('projects')->all();

        // Get project data
        $modelProjects = new Projects;
        $searchModelProjects = new \backend\models\ProjectsSearch();
        $dataProviderProjects = $searchModelProjects->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $queryProjects = Projects::find()->with('parent','tasks')->all();



        return $this->render('productionsite', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'searchModelProjects' => $searchModelProjects,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'dataProviderProjects' => $dataProviderProjects,
            'query' => $query,
            'queryProjects' => $queryProjects,
            'model' => $model,
            'modelProjects' => $modelProjects,
            'model2' => $model2,
        ]);


    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {



            if ($model->username == '****' or $model->username =='****')  {
            return $this->render('index', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
            }

                else {
                return $this->redirect(['productionsite', 
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
                }


        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }


    public function actionDetails()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        if ($request->isAjax && $request->isPost) {
            $id = $request->post('id');
            //add your model code here
            $customer = Customers::find()->where(['=', 'id', $id])->one();
            return $this->renderAjax('//site/frames/_list', ['model' => $customer]);
        }
        Yii::$app->end();
    }

}
```

Comment: first of all you didnt added the `DetailView` code in which you are currently showing the details please add complete code that is related to the problem, and secondly you are trying to bind an `onclick` event to an anchor that is populating inside the `GridView` and you want that anchor to work in a way that it refreshes/updates the div that has the `DetailView` with the information related to the project in the `GridView` is that correct?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response - i added the detail view now. And second: I have a view (_list.php) with 4 divs, named upper/lower and left/right. I am trying to show the detailview in the div "upperleft" of an item shown AND clicked in gridview in the "lowerright" without manually refreshing the whole page or redirecting to a new one. I will rework my question a bit more accurate during the day.

Comment: the problem that you are having after updates is because i didnt added the `e.preventDefault()` in the code for onclick, please copy the code block for the anchor again, and see what is in the console,then if you are looking to get the customer details you just need to update your variable name that you are sending in the ajax to the controller action rest is all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the third parameter for the `options` that renders all options provided as `name=>value` pair as the attributes of the resulting tag you are adding it in the `url` parameter [**`See HTML::a() API Documentation`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a()-detail).

It should be like

```
return Html::a(
    $model->project_name, 
    ['/projects/view', 'id' => $model->id],
    ['onclick'=>"YourJavascriptStatement()"]
);
```

So if you want to add `onclick` attribute to the anchor it should go into the third parameter of the `Html::a()` function as `name=>value` pair taking the attribute name(onclick) and the value(javascript function or statement) for it.

Now looking to your problem you need to

1. Bind the click event to the anchors by assigning a common class, and make an ajax call that should send the `project_id` of the currently clicked link and in the success function, it should update the `HTML` of the `div` in which you are showing the `DetailView`.

update your `projektname` column definition in `GridView` to the following

```
 [
    'label' => 'Projektname',
    'attribute' => 'project_name',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) { 
        return Html::a($model->project_name, '#.' , ['data'=>['project'=>$model->id],'class'=>'project_details']);
    },
],
```

add the following to the top of your view file `_list.php`. Update the url to the relevant path

```
$js=<<<JS
$(document).on('click','a.project_details',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/controller/action', //change this to the relevant controller and action names
        data:{project_id:id},
        success:function(data){$('#yourDetailViewDivId').html(data)},
        error:function(xhr,statusCode,errorText){alert(errorText)}
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

2. Add an action to your controller get the `project_id` from the ajax request and fetch the project details from table against that `project_id` and pass it to the view but use `return $this->renderAjax('viewname')` instead of `return $this->render('viewname')`. See [**`HERE`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045365/what-is-renderajax-how-is-it-different-from-render) for the difference.

Example action

```
public function actionDetails()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if ($request->isAjax && $request->isPost) {
        $project_id = $request->post('project_id');
        //add your model code here
        $project = Projects::find()->where(['=', 'id', $project_id])->one();
        return $this->renderAjax('viewname', ['model' => $project]);
    }
    Yii::$app->end();
}
```

3. Create a view that should have a `DetailView` and show the details of the selected model.

should be similar to the following add the table attributes

```
<?=
    DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'options' => ['class' => 'table'],
        'attributes' => [
            //add your model attributes here you want to show
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It was a great help.